# VScode cannot modify the settings and in the settings.json show "End of file expected" error

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, configuration

That day,i wanna modify my font size in the VScode.But it pops out `Failed to write user settings. Please turn it on to correct any errors / warnings and try again.`.Then i turn to the `settings.json` while i click the button `open the settings`.There is parenthese`[8,1]`(the third one) showing an error called`End of file expected.jsonc`.Following is my `settings,json`.

```
{
"workbench.colorTheme": "One Dark Pro",
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
"files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
"terminal.integrated.enableMultiLinePasteWarning": false,
"editor.unicodeHighlight.invisibleCharacters": false,
"python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
"python.formatting.provider": "yapf",
"python.linting.flake8Args": ["--max-line-length=248"],
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": false
```

}

i tried to delete the second`[7,1]` and the third`[8,1]` parentheses `} and {` to combine these,but not works.
i also attempt to add a comma or a semicolon `, or ;` between the second parenthese and the third one. but also in vain.

Comment: Hi, have you tried removing parentheses 2 & 3 and putting a comma at the end of the line that says `"editor.unicodeHighlight.invisibleCharacters": false`?. If that doesn't work could you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75066262/edit) your post to show the modified file you created by removing the parenthesis? It's not entirely clear to me what you did.

Comment: what you show is not a valid JSON file, a settings.json file is 1 object `{}` with properties

Comment: @ThatCoolCoder          Thank u with utter sincerity for ur assistance.honestly, i really don't know how to reply ur answer,hhh,cuz it's my first time to post a question. ur answer did correct that error, but more errors pop out, I have configured both Python and C++ environments on vscode. But after the modification, Python files crashes and can't work with many errors. And I have already edited my post.